# How to get rid of decimal point in the legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

Here is the code I used to make the visualization:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(reduced_data,columns=['pca1','pca2','pca3','pca4','pca5','pca6','pca7'])
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="pca1", y="pca2", hue=H12022_full['cluster'],palette=['green','orange','brown','dodgerblue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red'], data=results)
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.0f}'))
```

This is the result:

[image]

I wanted to know how I could get rid of the decimals in the legend. So instead of 1.0 it will be just 1?

Comment: `hue=H12022_full['cluster'].astype(str)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
actual_legends = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()[1]
legend = [int(float(l)) for l in actual_legends]
plt.legend(legend)
```

Comment: I got this in when I put it in there. 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'

Comment: I have updated the solution, please check

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @mwaskom, use `hue=H12022_full['cluster'].astype(int)`, however with change of int instead of str.